# Not able to install Nuget Package " Microsoft.AspNet.Odata" in Web API, ASP.Net 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, odata, nuget-package, webapi2

I am new with Web API 2. I am trying to create an application using VS 2013 Update 4, ASP.Net 4.5, while trying to install "Microsoft.AspNet.Odata" Nuget Package,l getting following error:

```
 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.2.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 6.0.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (≥ 1.0.0 && < 2.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (≥ 1.0.0 && < 2.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.OData.Core (≥ 7.0.0 && < 8.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Spatial (= 7.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.OData.Edm (= 7.0.0)'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 1.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Spatial 7.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Spatial 7.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.OData.Edm 7.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.OData.Edm 7.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.OData.Core 7.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.OData.Core 7.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData 6.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData 6.0.0'.
Adding 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0' to WebAPI_Empty.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Any help to proceed are appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: How did you try to install? Is it through Package Manager Console?

Comment: yes, i tried but getting same error

Comment: Can you pls paste the command which you have given?

Comment: Command is : **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.OData**

Comment: Have you gone through this..
http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#07-02-5-4-rc

Comment: Just checked, now its working fine. Thanks Buddy.

Comment: @nitish can you tell how you solved?  I'm having the same issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade the OData package to a previous version.  Right now, the current version is 6.1.0, but the most recent version that I found that works is 5.10.0

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.OData -Version 5.10.0
```

See package versions at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/